# Bad bind variables in oracle stored procedure

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures

I am totally new to stored procedures. I have a query and I wanna use it for a web service. I am going to use Nhibernate. I have tried couple of procedures and worked well. But this one giving me problems. I tried to compile the stored procedure but giving me errors.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE GET_RSM_LIFE_AGENT_DUES (p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, :Year IN number, :Month IN number, :Branch IN number, :Agency IN number) AS
BEGIN
OPEN p_recordset for

select     :Year  as required_year, :Month  as required_month, 
           case when pmagt = 0 then D.branch_code else E.branch_code end as branch_code,
           case when pmagt = 0 then D.branch_name else E.branch_name end as branch_name,
           case when pmagt = 0 then D.region else E.region end as region,
           pmagt as agency,
           status || ' ' || int || ' ' || name as agent_name,
           pmpol as policy_no,
           pmcom as commence_date,
           pmtrm as term,
           pmmod as policy_mode,

            case WHEN pmtbl not in (51,22,74,75,76) and ((:Year - SUBSTR (pmcom,1,4)) * 12 + to_number(:Month) - SUBSTR (pmcom,-4,2)) < 12 then 'FYR'
            WHEN pmtbl not in (51,22,74,75,76) and ((:Year - SUBSTR (pmcom,1,4)) * 12 + to_number(:Month) - SUBSTR (pmcom,-4,2)) >= 12  then 'Renewal' else '' end as premium_type,

           case when llprm is not null and pmprm < llprm then llprm else pmprm end as due_Premium,
           case when llprm is not null then llprm else 0 end as due_paid_premium            

    FROM   lphs.premast A left outer join lclm.ledger B on (A.pmpol = B.llpol) and (to_number(:Year || :Month) = lldue)
           left outer join agent.agent C on (A.pmagt = C.agency)
           left outer join BAU.SLIC_BRANCH_LIST D on (A.pmobr = D.csp_code)
           left outer join BAU.SLIC_BRANCH_LIST E on (C.branch = E.csp_code)

    WHERE   add_months(to_date(PMCOM,'YYYYMMDD'),PMTRM*12) >= add_months( to_date(:Year || :Month || 01 ,'YYYYMMDD'),1) 
            and to_date(pmcom,'yyyymmdd') < to_date(:Year || :Month || 01 ,'YYYYMMDD') 
            and pmmod <> 5
            and stid in ('Ag' , 'ME', 'Or')
            and case when to_date(pmcom,'yyyymmdd') >= to_date(:Year || :Month || 01 ,'YYYYMMDD') then 'N' 
                when pmmod = 4 then 'Y'
                when pmmod = 3 and remainder ( abs( to_number ( substr (pmcom, 5,2) )  - to_number ( :Month ) )   , 3 ) =0 then 'Y' 
                when pmmod = 2 and remainder ( abs( to_number ( substr (pmcom, 5,2) )  - to_number ( :Month ) )   , 6 ) =0 then 'Y' 
                when pmmod = 1 and remainder ( abs( to_number ( substr (pmcom, 5,2) )  - to_number ( :Month ) )   , 12 ) =0 then 'Y' else 'N' end = 'Y'

           and case when pmagt = 0 then D.branch_code else E.branch_code end = :Branch      
          and pmagt = :Agency    

END GET_RSM_LIFE_AGENT_DUES;
```

Error.....

```
Error(2,67): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'YEAR'
Error(2,67): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:     <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    current delete exists prior 
Error(2,84): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'MONTH'
```

Comment: It's excellent that you're trying to use bind variables, but all PL/SQL variables (including parameters) are automatically bind variables, so you don't need to worry about the variables inside the procedure, only the ones you're passing into the procedure when you call it, as per Littlefoot's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Remove colons from within the procedure. Those are procedure's parameters, so use them as such. Pass their values as e.g.

```
declare
  l_out sys_refcursor;
begin
  GET_RSM_LIFE_AGENT_DUES (l_out, :Year, :Month, :Branch, :Agency);
end;
```